# How to bypass codeigniter security to access project directly

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to access the project but it ask for install like basic configuration but i want to remove it framework is codeigniter..!!!

index.php code...below

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'pre_installation');

// we don't want to access the main project before installation. redirect to installation page
if (ENVIRONMENT === 'pre_installation') {
    $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

    $domain = preg_replace('/index.php.*/', '', $domain); //remove everything after index.php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $domain = 'https://' . $domain;
    } else {
        $domain = 'http://' . $domain;
    }

    header("Location: $domain./install/index.php");
    exit;
}
```

.htaccess file code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#Cache
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

but i want to access directly the controller and its functions but it keeps redirect me back to install page

Answer (score 1):

Installation page is coming because your CI `ENVIRONMENT` variable has been set to `pre_installation`.
So change `ENVIRONMENT` to `production` or `development`.
**Like this:** `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');` or `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just walk through the CodeIgniter wizard to properly install the basics. You can not be sure that any thing is configured before installation, since that is the whole point of installation.

If you really want to learn the hard way then as pGauR says you can change the `ENVIRONMENT` definition. That will run the code until you run into the next error.

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```